# Index table after import table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am facing issue of import data from csv in my mysql data table. It have primary key called id. After import data from csv, I can sell all data in database from phpmyadmin but I am getting nothing as result via query from php. My query is like below

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM questions where id>".$index);
```

Can anyone help me for solve the issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Does the same query work when you run it in PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: I suggest you try some basic troubleshooting first; what's the value of `$index` just before calling mysqli_query()? What's the value of `$result` after running the query? Is there a MySQL error, PHP error, or just no results found? What if you hardcode a value instead of using `$index` here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was symbol in one of my row and so why I was facing issue. I have removed it and solved issue. Thanks

Comment: In that case, it sounds like you're not properly escaping your queries and protecting against SQL injection.